# Hide div if URL hash begins with word in Javascript

Tags: javascript, show-hide

How could I hide divs that begin with id "news" but also contain a number like "news1" "news2" etc if the URL hash doesnt contain "news".

like hide if `someurl.com/#events`. but show any "news" div   if  `someurl.com/news1`

need in regular JS

thanks,

Comment: `"someurl.com/news1".split('/')[1].indexOf('news') === 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try This:-**

```js
$(function(){
  var url = window.location.hash;
 
  if(url.indexOf('news') > -1){
    $("div[id^='news']").hide();
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="news1">News1</div><br>

<div id="news2">news2</div><br>
<div id="news3">news3</div><br>
<div id="event">event</div><br>
```

**Update: (Using Pure JavaScript)**

```js
(function() {
   var url = window.location.hash;
  /* for testing set the hash to 'news' */
    url='news';

 if(url.indexOf('news') > -1){
 
  var bodyDOM = document.body;
  bodyDOM.querySelectorAll("[id^='news']").forEach(function(item, index){
    item.style.display='none';
  });
 }
})();
```

```html
<div id="news1">News1</div><br>

<div id="news2">news2</div><br>
<div id="news3">news3</div><br>
<div id="event">event</div><br>
```

Comment: thanks, is there a way to do this w/o JQuery. i just realized Id need to do it in plain js

Comment: @user718229, I have updated my answer. please take a look.  For a visual representation, I have set the URL hash to 'news' please remove it while using the code

Answer (score 1):

The script hasn't been tested. It does these steps:

1. Looking for the word "#news" in URL. In our case, if there aren't any word.
2. For each div with the ID "new" or similar
3. Add a CSS to this div to hide it.

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function () {
       if(window.location.href.indexOf("#news") < 0) {
           $("div[id^='news']").css('display', 'none');
       }
   });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 0):

If you put a class on all the divs you'd want this apply to, you can do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.CLASSNAME').each(function(i) {
        if($(this).val().indexOf('WORD_YOURE_LOOKING_FOR') > -1) {
            $(this).css('display', 'none');
         }
    );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well you can access the hash in a URL like so:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
```

I'm not 100% clear what you want to do at that point. If you wanted to show the news1 div, you'd do this:

```
if(hash == 'news1') {
   $('#news1').show();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var hash = window.location.hash;
$('[id^="'+hash+'"').hide();
```